# Show that $X = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nA$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a linear space and $A$ be a convex and absorbing subset of $X$. Then, $X = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nA$.

I don't want a solution to this, only a hint because I'm stuck. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What is your definition of absorbing?

Comment: Try working from any of the equivalent definitions on the wikipedia page.

Comment: @podiki A set $A$ is absorbing iff $\forall x \in X$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\forall \lambda \in (- \delta, + \delta) \Rightarrow \lambda x \in A$.

Answer (score 2):

I know you are only asking for a hint, but the slightest hint here is an answer itself:

$A$ is absorbing, thus for all $x\in X$ there exists $\delta=\delta_x>0$ such that for all scalars $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|<\delta_x$, we have $\lambda\cdot x\in A$.

Obviously $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nA\subset X$. On the other hand, if $x\in X$, then find $\delta_x>0$ such that $|\lambda|<\delta_x\implies\lambda x\in A$. The condition $\lambda x\in A$ is written equivalently as $x\in\frac{1}{\lambda}A$. Just take $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\delta_x$. Then $\frac{1}{n}x\in A$, i.e. $x\in nA$.